# Android: 3-Stage SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a LinearLayout with a ListView. And a layout above it, aligned to right, also having a ListView.
I want to implement this upper layout as a 3-stage horizontal SlidingDrawer (right to left) like widget with 3 stages as: 
1) Drawer completely closed
2) Drawer 50% open
3) Drawer completely open to occupy whole screen
When the drawer will be 50% open, both the ListViews should be able to catch the click events.
Can anyone help me please with how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: To hve horizontal sliding just change orientation.
Its easy to implement 1 and 3, refer to : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html,
Its not possible to customize the animation and detect the 50%. You have to create your own CustomSlidingDrawer, http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-damn-that-sliding-drawer/

Comment: Thanks Anis. Yes, I know that making it horizontal is no big deal. But I am stuck over how do I customize it acc. to my requirement.Here is a [project](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/) I am working for CustomSlidingDrawer. But I am not able to get through it.

Comment: Its a UI design requirement of the project I am working on!

Comment: I would suggest to create a transparent TextView on 50% after that, use ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener and relay on its visibility change to handle the 50%

Comment: I am sorry for giving incomplete information. I have a listview below and the drawer will be on top of this. And the drawer will also have a listView on it. When the drawer will be open 50%, the listview below should respond to the touch events(itemClick). So, if I place the trasparent TextView, if I am right the listview below will not receive any events.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link. That should get you started:

http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-sliding-drawer/

Code without the layout would be something like:

```
public class animation extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
CheckBox c1,c2,c3;
int key=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    final TransparentPanel popup = (TransparentPanel) findViewById(R.id.popup_window);
    popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.show_popup_button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(key==0){
                key=1;
                popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slid3_n);
            }
            else if(key==1){
                key=0;
                popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slid4_n);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

That is just a "two stage" drawer. For an inbetween stage or basically it is two drawers in one you would have to adjust the code to yourself a bit.

Comment: Thanks SunnySonic for the link. But after going through the code it seems that, just the visibility of the pop-up is adjusted on click event acc. to condition. 
Whereas I need it to animate the drawer like SlidingDrawer does. And also the user should be able to open/close the handle by moving the handle(touch and move) and not just on clicking it.

Comment: you can set animations for opening and closing. check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html     I dont know though about the "touch and drag that you would like. you might not be able to use SlidingDrawer native class. on this page though it is talking about dragging the handle. have a look at that: http://www.itwizard.ro/sliding-drawer-193.html